# Calling NASM function in C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to learn x86 assembler, and I want to call a *NASM* function in *C*. When i run my program I get this error:

> Segmentation fault (Core dumped)

I've tried dozens of variations of my simple test function but it stops every time at the same position.

Here are my `asm` and `c` files:

div.asm:

```
global _test

_test:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ebx
    mov     eax, [ebp+8]
    mov     ebx, [ebp+12]
    div     ebx
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int test (unsigned int, unsigned int);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", div(85,5));
    return 0;
}
```

I compile & link the files with:

```
nasm -f elf -o div.o div.asm
gcc -m32 -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -m32 -o run div.o main.o
```

I use a `64 Bit Linux` in a `Virtual Machine`.

What is my mistake here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: use a debugger to find out which insn it's faulting on.  See [the FAQ section of the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), you have a couple of them: mismatched push/pop, and a `div` problem.

Comment: Oh good point, yeah, Linux doesn't mangle names with a leading `_`.  The `test` function you're calling isn't even the `_test` function you assembled!  Since it links, the symbol must exist in some library, I guess?  Again, debugger FTW.  Compile with `-g`.  Like `gcc -m32 -Wall -Wextra -Og -g main.c div.o -o run`

Comment: Damn. Deleted my comment by accident. Delete the underscore, and try reducing the function to just 'xor eax, eax' and 'ret'.

Comment: I tried to debug, the function stops in the div function: 0xf7e4d55d <+13>: mov %eax,(%ecx)

Comment: Wait a second. You call a function called div, but you haven't defined it anywhere in your code. The function you defined in assembly is called 'test'

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to change it too, but now I have a Floating Point exception :/

Comment: Floating point exception is because you are [dividing](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html) EDX:EAX by EBX and the quotient likely isn't fitting in a 32-bit register. You don't clear _EDX_. Try putting `xor edx, edx` before your div to ensure the the top 32 bits of the dividend are zero.

Comment: Also,look up the calling conventions of your platform.

Comment: Okay, after clearing EDX the function uses div correctly, but stops with Segmentation fault while return

Comment: He @Leandros, `div` is a machine instruction - unsigned divide.

Comment: @DanielHiller: did you read the FAQ section of the x86 tag wiki I linked earlier?  I already pointed out your problem with `div`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help, now it works :)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: He's talking about the C code.  It has a prototype for `test()`, but a call to `div()`.

Answer (score 4):

You forget to pop ebx (or at least make the stack in order):

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
push    ebx         ; you push it here
mov     eax, [ebp+8]
mov     ebx, [ebp+12]
xor     edx,edx     ; ..and you must zero edx
div     ebx
pop     ebx         ; forgot to pop it here
pop     ebp
ret
```

Comment: This isn't the only problem. The Div is doing unsigned division of EDX:EAX divided by EBX, but _EDX_ is not zeroed out. This can lead to incorrect result or a division fault because the quotient may not be representable in 32 bits.

Comment: You need to restore the caller's `ebx`!  Better would be to not use a call-preserved register in the first place (e.g. use `ecx`).  Even better, `div [ebp+12]`.

Comment: Whatever, but if he doesn't cleanup the stack then `pop ebp` will pop the wrong base poinetr and the `ret` will jump to anywhere, hence the seg fault.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: The load part of `pop ebx` is necessary.  Sure `add esp, 4` (not `add sp, 4`), or the traditional `mov esp, ebp` part of `leave` would restore `esp` so `pop ebp` / `ret` would work, but there'd still be a serious bug of clobbering `ebx`.  It's not a valid suggestion.

Comment: But Paul, since he is creating a 32-bit application on Linux, the CDECL specifies that certain registers need to be preserved by the function. In particular: _Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are caller-saved, and the rest are callee-saved_ . If _EBX_ isn't actually restored you can be in for some nasty bugs later on. It may seem to work to begin with, but eventually that bug will bite you in the butt.

Comment: @PeterCordes, what is the "bogus"? He has to get the stack in order and so remove 4 bytes from the stack to be able tot pop the corect base pointer and do a correct return. The stack grows down, so adding will remove it. I don't know whether he wanted to do anything with ebx. Just showing the stack error.

Comment: @PeterCordes, correct, should be `esp`, not `sp. Fixed that. Thx.

Comment: You show the stack error but your suggestion _Instead of pop ebx you can do add sp,4_ is wrong. _EBX_ needs to be preserved by the function, so you must restore _EBX_'s value before returning. `add sp,4` fixes the stack but doesn't restore _EBX_ per the [CDECL calling convention for 32-bit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl).

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I see. I removed the line from my answer.

Comment: The division problem should still be fixed or you **might** find the program will fault with a division error even after resolving the segfault. Most of the time the result will be wrong unless _EDX_ happened to be zero before the function was called.

Comment: @michael-Petch, I added zeroeing of edx.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear if you ever got your problem solved. In addition to the other issues, you would need to make your function call in your `main.c` match the call in `div.asm`. For example if you have created an assembly function `_test`, you need to declare it as `extern` and actually use the function in `main`. e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int _test (unsigned int, unsigned int);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", _test (85,5));    /* you are calling div here, not _test */
    return 0;
}
```

(your function name is **not** the name for your assembly object file `div.o` -- and as pointed out in the comments, `div` is an unsigned division declared in `stdlib.h` along with `ldiv`, and `lldiv`)

Your `global` declaration in your assembly function file must match the name you declared in `main`. e.g.:

```
    global _test

_test:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     eax, [ebp+8]
    xor     edx, edx
    div     dword [ebp+12]
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Now, you can compile, link and run your test file:

```
$ nasm -f elf -o div.o div.asm
$ gcc -m32 -c -o main.o main.c
$ gcc -m32 -o run div.o main.o
$./run
17
```

or for the compilation/link, simply:

```
$ nasm -f elf -o div.o div.asm
$ gcc -m32 -o run main.c div.o
```